# Facing issue with gulp task on linux environment

Tags: ubuntu, gulp

I am writing a gulp task to concatenate some html files and providing an array of source files to gulp as below:

```
['./base/**/*.html', '!./base/vendor/*.html']
```

This works well when run on windows but on ubuntu it is not generating any concatenated file, also not showing any error.

When tried on ubuntu by changing the source files array as below:

```
['./base/**/*.html']
```

it is working.

Comment: Simple: you don't have any `.html` files except in `./base/vendor/`.

Comment: @SvenSchoenung, the concatenated file is getting generated on windows but not on ubuntu.